# Hide body scroll bar for only one component in angular

Tags: css, angular

I want to disable overflow: hidden style for only one component. This style is in my style.scss like so

.Visible-scroll{
overflow: auto
}

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it will be difficult to help you but you can override with !important.

.Invisible-scroll { overflow: hidden !important }

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: I have service-view module in the app module. Now in service-view module there is list-work-component. Here i want to hide body scroll bar when list-work component is loaded. i mean - i want to hide body scroll bar in only list-work view.
I have applied you given answer. but it is not working.

Comment: Can you, please, post the code you're using now.